# Counting number of state pairs that are not orderable

Tags: order-theory

I'm looking at a problem where I have a space of states $\mathcal{S} = \{0,1,\ldots,m\}^n$ where $m$ and $n$ are given integers. Consider an elementwise ordering between two states $s,s'\in\mathcal{S}$, denoted by $\succeq$, where $s\succeq s'$ if $s_i\ge s_i'$ for all $i=1,\ldots,n$. For example $s=(0,1,1)\succeq s'=(0,1,0)$ but $s=(0,1,1)\not\succeq s'=(1,1,0)$, where in the later case $s$ and $s'$ are not orderable, termed unorderable.

**Goal:** To determine the number of unorderable pairs of states, with respect to the elementwise partial order, for a given $m$ and $n$.

**Example 1:** Consider $m=1$ and $n=2$, then $\mathcal{S}=\{0,1\}^2$ and the unorderable pairs of states are simply $(0,1)\not\succeq(1,0)$ (all other pairs of states are orderable). Note that I treat the case $(1,0)\not\succeq(0,1)$ as equivalent to $(0,1)\not\succeq(1,0)$.

**Example 2:** Consider $m=1$ and $n=3$, then $\mathcal{S}=\{0,1\}^3$ and the unorderable pairs of states are
\begin{align*}
(0,0,1)&\not\succeq(0,1,0)\\
(0,0,1)&\not\succeq(1,0,0)\\
(0,0,1)&\not\succeq(1,1,0)\\
(0,1,0)&\not\succeq(1,0,0)\\
(0,1,0)&\not\succeq(1,0,1)\\
(0,1,1)&\not\succeq(1,0,0)\\
(0,1,1)&\not\succeq(1,0,1)\\
(0,1,1)&\not\succeq(1,1,0)\\
(1,1,0)&\not\succeq(1,0,1)\\
\end{align*}
How can one characterize the set of unorderable states for larger $m$ and $n$?

Comment: When you say $\{0,m\}^n$, do you mean $\{0,1,2,\dots,m\}^n$?

Comment: @MikeEarnest Yes! I've clarified the question, thank you.

Comment: @bof Because I missed it :)

Comment: For $m=1$ the number of "unorderable" pairs is $2^{2n-1}+2^{n-1}-3^n.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of counting incomparable pairs of states, count the comparable ones.

How many pairs of states are there where $a\preceq b$? For each coordinate, $i$, the pair $(a_i,b_i)$ must satisfy $a_i\le b_i$. There are $\binom{m+1}2+m+1=(m+1)(m+2)/2$ ways to choose $(a_i,b_i)$. Therefore, there are $[(m+1)(m+2)/2]^n$ pairs of states where $a\preceq b$. Similarly, there are $[(m+1)(m+2)/2]^n$ pairs of states where $a\succeq b$. In total, the number of pairs of comparable states is
$$
[(m+1)(m+2)/2]^n + [(m+1)(m+2)/2]^n - (m+1)^n
$$
Note that we subtracted $(m+1)^n$ at the end, since the pairs where $a=b$ were double counted.

Finally, subtract the above quantity from $(m+1)^{2n}$, the total number of pairs of states, and divide by two to turn ordered pairs into unordered pairs.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if this is related to the antichain of the poset $(\mathcal{S},\succeq)$?

Comment: Yes, you are counting antichains with exactly two elements.